# Sum Aggregation on decimal value does work as expected in ADF mapping dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have below dataset as .csv file in datalake.

| id (int) | value (double) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25.900 |
| 1 | 25.694 |

On doing Sum(value) on the basis of ID column using aggregation activity in dataflow, The result of sum is not expected which is 51.593999999999994.

The Expected result is 51.594.

Can anyone help me why the extra decimal coming in result.

[image: data preview 1]

[image: data preview 2]

Answer (score 0):

You can round the sum results to get the required number using the [round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#round) function.

Expression: `round(sum(value),3)`

[image]

Aggregate output:

[image]

Comment: Great it works ...But why it is behaving like this ,it's a bug in ADF ?